# MessageBox in const function

Tags: c++, mfc

I wrote this simple const class method:

```
void CTest::MSGTest() const
{
    MessageBox(_T("This is a simple test"));
}
```

This method has an error:

> The object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function CTest::MessageBoxW

I know this is because i use the **const**. A method can be a const method if no member variables are modify while the execution. I would like to know which variables the MessageBox modify and how the modification manifests.

I think it is the handler m_hWnd, but I don't know.

Comment: `I would like to know which variables the MessageBox modify and how the modification manifests.`  MFC comes with source code.  Why not look at the source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't that neither your function nor `MessageBox` modify any members variables - they don't and that's easy to see.

The problem is that `MessageBox` is not marked as `const` and so you have a `const` member function (yours) calling non `const` one (`MessageBox`). This isn't allowed and that's the issue.

So why isn't it marked `const`? I doubt you will ever get a definitive answer to that question if one reason really exists.

Personally, I suspect it's a combination of factors that caused it to not be `const` originally and now it is what it is.

One potential reason is that a lot of internal MFC bits and pieces involve the manipulation and adjustment of maps - for example maps which associate windows HWND objects to MFC `CWnd` objects.

It's possible that they had to relax the use of `const` to account for calls to non `const` functions deep down the call chain in places that users never see.

So why not use `mutable` then or maybe even `const_cast`? Remember that MFC has been around for a long time and when it was designed the Microsoft compiler might not have support for some of the more exotic features of C++ at the time.

Comment: The last sentence is key.  MFC has its own implementations of virtual inheritance and exceptions, because those weren't standard C++ features at the time.

Comment: And if you use MessageBox in multiple methods similar to MSGTest(), you could write your own `MsgBox(same signature as MessageBox) const` to wrap Nik's work-around, then utiiize your MsgBox method over MFC's `CWnd::MessageBox`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if `CTest` is derived from `CWnd` (explicitly or not) - showing a dialog box on this `CWnd` object means changing the state of window/control. Assume `CTest` is derived from a `CDialog`, and pressing some button causes this function (`CTest::MsgTest`) to be called. It effectively means that state of the dialog-box has changed (from user's perspective). It is not important if modal or modeless dialog is shown - the state has changed, hence the method shouldn't be `const`.